# Using string constants with wildcards/variables

Tags: java

I am curious about some special case of constants.

Imagine you have some error mesages like `The user 'alexander' already exists.` So, the user should be variable and this error message should be a constant like `public static final ERROR_MESSAGE_LOGIN="The user (insert username here) already exists."`.

Is that possible in Java? If not, is there any nice workaround? Have you other hints, that I should know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [message bundles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageintro.html), which let you prepare templated messages and fill in variables at runtime. This is also the approach used for internationalization, so that you can also specify your messages in multiple languages with no extra difficulty.

Various tools such as expression languages, Thymeleaf, and JSP offer built-in support for message formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander, Java provides a better way to dealing with some UI Messages and even adds Internacionalization features.
You should give a look at: [Java Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't use variables in constants, but you can create a methode like

```java
public String getErrorMsg(String user){
return "The user " + user + " already exists."
```

}